# Manually alter data on the CSV file resulted in the data displayed as NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, utf-16

So I have this CSV file generated from the following code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input_file.csv', encoding="utf-16")
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
df['english'] = df['Comment'].apply(translator.translate, src='id', dest='en')
#print(df)
#print(df['english'])
from textblob import TextBlob
def sentiment_calc(text):
    try:
        return TextBlob(text).sentiment
    except:
        return None
df['english'] = df['english'].astype(str) #change type to string 
df['sentiment']=df['english'].apply(lambda text: TextBlob(text).sentiment)
#print(df['sentiment'])
df.to_csv('output_file.csv', mode='w', index=False, encoding="utf-16")
```

here are the results

```
Comment  ...                                          sentiment
0     seni bahasa pemerintah new normal protokol kes...  ...  Sentiment(polarity=0.1431818181818182, subject...
1     we need thanos to bring balance to the our uni...  ...          Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
2     terserah lah mau ngomong apa pusing denger dia...  ...          Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
3     mirip protokol di parkiran motor helm hilang r...  ...          Sentiment(polarity=0.6, subjectivity=1.0)
4     ga kebayang kita hidup dijaman yg serba salah ...  ...  Sentiment(polarity=0.3181818181818182, subject...
                                                ...  ...                                                ...
4966  klu pake sarungtangan ke mall megang ini itu m...  ...      Sentiment(polarity=0.25, subjectivity=0.3125)
4967  bukannya ini orang yg bikin mesjid dg konsep i...  ...  Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0666666...
4968  ribet bnget cuma di tahap implementasi akan su...  ...  Sentiment(polarity=-0.3333333333333333, subjec...
4969  mal dibuka bahasa adaptasi tau g sih covid ini...  ...  Sentiment(polarity=0.21250000000000002, subjec...
4970  kenapa kita pilih new normal kalau ternyata ad...  ...  Sentiment(polarity=0.053856749311294756, subje...

[4971 rows x 3 columns]
```

But then I need to manually change some numbers on the sentiment column. After I change those numbers, when I read the CSV again using `df = pd.read_csv('output_file.csv', encoding="utf_16")` to continue my analysis. The entire column becomes NaN.

```
Comment  english  sentiment
0     seni bahasa pemerintah new normal protokol kes...      NaN        NaN
1     we need thanos to bring balance to the our uni...      NaN        NaN
2     terserah lah mau ngomong apa pusing denger dia...      NaN        NaN
3     mirip protokol di parkiran motor helm hilang r...      NaN        NaN
4     ga kebayang kita hidup dijaman yg serba salah ...      NaN        NaN
                                                ...      ...        ...
4966  klu pake sarungtangan ke mall megang ini itu m...      NaN        NaN
4967  bukannya ini orang yg bikin mesjid dg konsep i...      NaN        NaN
4968  ribet bnget cuma di tahap implementasi akan su...      NaN        NaN
4969  mal dibuka bahasa adaptasi tau g sih covid ini...      NaN        NaN
4970  kenapa kita pilih new normal kalau ternyata ad...      NaN        NaN

[4971 rows x 3 columns]
```

Any solutions to make my sentiment column not becoming NaN?

[the csv file](https://intip.in/SCOd)

Comment: Share manually changed csv file please. How You should read file depends of the file format.

Comment: Here are my csv file https://intip.in/SCOd/

Comment: [The csv file from your link](https://intip.in/SCOd) has incorrectly formatted data lines enclosed in double quotes (however the csv header is correct `Comment,english,sentiment`). Hence, all data are in the column `Comment` while columns `english` and `sentiment` are not defined… For instance, 88th line (chosen a short one) in your file is literally `"mantap ,""Translated(src=id, dest=en, text=great, pronunciation=great, extra_data=""""{'translat..."""")"",""Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)"""`…